# Timestamp as incremental Identifier

Tags: ios, session, timestamp, connection, identifier

I am working in a personal project where I need to support communication between devices **(android/iPhone)** via Wifi/BT/BLE etc. To support this at some point I need to assign some incremental identifiers within each device.

Like, Device A create id_b and id_c to communicate with Device B and Device C in different time period. And sometime Device A need to compare the ids- which one is created later.

As per as I know, we can solve this problem by binding timestamp with the id, right ? but what if Device A's time will manually changed to previous date by user ?

What is the best solution to keep session id which can be compared as quantitative measure ?

Thanks in advance